# Error in p5.js: "pushMatrix() not used, see push()"

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Every time I run my code, it gives me an error:

> p5.js says: An error with message "pushMatrix() not used, see push()" occured inside the p5js library when pushMatrix was called (on line 175 in sketch.js [/sketch.js:175:13])
>
> If not stated otherwise, it might be an issue with the arguments passed to pushMatrix. (http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pushMatrix)

However, `pushMatrix()` does not exist in my code.
When I try to fix it by replacing `push()` with `pushMatrix()`, it gives me the same error:

> p5.js says: An error with message "pushMatrix() not used, see push()" occured inside the p5js library when pushMatrix was called (on line 175 in sketch.js [/sketch.js:175:13])
>
> If not stated otherwise, it might be an issue with the arguments passed to pushMatrix. (http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pushMatrix)

My code: https://pastebin.com/gMxwvJLA (StackOverflow wouldn't let me post the question because the code was so large)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: `pushMatrix()` is not a valid function in `p5`. It doesn't exist.  You want to find and replace all usages of `pushMatrix()` with [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and `popMatrix()` with [`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop).

With those replacements your code runs without any errors and I see a square spinning around in the center of the canvas.

The error message is not particularly helpful, but looking at [the source code](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/374acfb44588bfd565c54d61264df197d798d121/src/core/legacy.js) clarifies things a lot.

```js
/**
 * @for p5
 * @requires core
 * These are functions that are part of the Processing API but are not part of
 * the p5.js API. In some cases they have a new name, in others, they are
 * removed completely. Not all unsupported Processing functions are listed here
 * but we try to include ones that a user coming from Processing might likely
 * call.
 */

import p5 from './main';

p5.prototype.pushStyle = function() {
  throw new Error('pushStyle() not used, see push()');
};

p5.prototype.popStyle = function() {
  throw new Error('popStyle() not used, see pop()');
};

p5.prototype.popMatrix = function() {
  throw new Error('popMatrix() not used, see pop()');
};

p5.prototype.pushMatrix = function() {
  throw new Error('pushMatrix() not used, see push()');
};

export default p5;
```

Comment: No, I explained in my question, "however, 'pushMatrix()' does not exist in my code."

Comment: @Voxel It literally does. EDIT: In many places. Are you sure you ran the updated code?

Comment: @Voxel You are calling `pushMatrix()` on line 175 and a bunch of other places.  Find and replace ALL of them with `push()` and do the same with `popMatrix()` to `pop()`.  I did this and it got rid of your error.  Here is the corrected code in the p5 web editor: https://editor.p5js.org/lindapaiste/sketches/loqBFD7i7

Comment: In your `pastebin` link, a simple search for `pushmatrix` indicates there are 24 occurrences. A quick find-and-replace would do the trick as @LindaPaiste said.

Comment: I think you must have had a `pushMatrix` in there by accident when you got the error the first time (when you said that you were using `push()`)

Comment: Whoops! I pasted the wrong code! When I removed the pushMatrix() and popMatrix() before, it actually didn't take effect because I didn't press the stop button first. It's no longer complaining.

Comment: Glad I could help :) It's an easy fix.